# Magnets: can you tell which pole is which without a second magnet?

Tags: electromagnetism

In other words, is there something fundamentally different between the "north" and "south" poles of the magnet or are they just relative terms.

If there isn't anything fundamental, what is the history behind "standardizing" what is called north and what is called south? Was it relative to the Earth's magnetic pole?

Comment: The body of your question seems to be more about fundamental meaning of "north" and "south" poles. However I the title you also ask if it is possible to tell which pole is which without another magnet. To answer that you could look which way a moving electron would be bend. I post this as a comment since this does not seem to be the mean focus of the question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yeah, the poles are relative, much like the sign of charge.  We can arbitrarily choose the electron's charge to be positive or negative, as long as we propagate that choice through our equations accordingly.  There would be nothing wrong with calling the charge of an electron positive as long as we then called the charge of a proton negative, picked up a negative sign in a few equations in E&M, etc.

Likewise, the choice of which pole is called "north" is arbitrary.  Historically, the choice was made because the north pole of a magnet points towards the north magnetic pole (fairly close to the geographic north pole).  This means that the north magnetic pole (up in the Arctic circle) is actually the magnetic south pole of the earth's magnetic field, and that the south magnetic pole (down in Antarctica) is actually the magnetic north pole.